# How does integrating trigonometric or ln functions work?

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I have the exercises that looks like $\int\frac{\arccos^3(2x)}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}dx$ and $\int\frac{\ln^5(x+1)}{x+1}dx$. I know how to deal with it when $\arccos$ or $\ln$ doesn't have power. I just need to replace the argument to something like $t = \arccos (2x)$ or $t = \ln(x+1)$ and use the formula $dx = 1/t dy$. But when the argument raise to the power I don't have any idea what to do.

Comment: Can you clarify your notation a little bit?

Comment: The same substitution works. Give it a try.

Comment: Please show us how you deal when there is no power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ln(x+1) = t$

Differentiating both sides:

$\implies\frac{dx}{x+1}=dt$

Then,

$\int \frac{ln^5(x+1)}{x+1}dx=\int t^5dt=\frac{t^6}{6}+c$, where c is an arbitrary constant.

Substituting value of t

$\implies\int \frac{ln^5(x+1)}{x+1}dx= \frac{ln^6(x+1)}{6}+c$

Similarly for $\int \frac{arccos(2x)}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Simple substitutions solve the first integral, too:
$$ \int \frac{\arccos^3(2x)}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto z/2}{=}\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\arccos^3(z)}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\,dz\stackrel{z\mapsto\cos\theta}{=}-\frac{1}{2}\int\theta^3\,d\theta=C-\frac{\theta^4}{8}=C-\frac{1}{8}\arccos^4(2z).$$